# What to make of properties as unary relations?

Tags: logic

Take for example the property or the unary relation, Man(x). It seems to "really" be a binary relation between x and {true, false} "under the hood." So would this make the notion of unary relations a more sophisticated shorthand for binary relations when the output is either true or false, i.e. are binary relations the building block of all relations and properties?

Comment: Not clear why *properties*, i.e. unary relations, are not useful.

Comment: I don't mean to say it's not useful. I'm pondering if it's more of a derivative notion based on a more fundamental binary relation.

Comment: By the same argument the binary relation p(x,{True,False}) is then really the 3-adic relation p(x,{True,False},{True,False}) which is really the 4-ary relation ....

Comment: True/false do not belong to the same domain as the other argument, so some extra complications are needed to make sense of it as binary, and we will still have to interpret the resulting relation as true or false, so it is hard to see the point in the first place. It is possible to "build" all relations from binary ones (on the *same* domain) by using conjunction (intersection) and existential quantification (projection), for example, but this is not how it is done.

Comment: I was thinking that once you've reached mappings to true or false, that justifies an ending with no need to go on and on. But I see the point about truth and falsity possibly being outside the domain, and that's interesting to think about, although I don't really see why we can't just say neither truth or falsity belongs to the set Man.

Answer (score -1):

This is not an unary relation, it is a binary under cutting pair unit. Binary is a man or a woman. But the binary in it's turn hasn't cut cause, cause of the relation is a dichotomy stance man-and-woman. The cause of man-and-woman(coup) = Baby. Baby is monad, when you keep in mind it's cause - family. Dichotomy dyad and it's cause is triede. Every relations can be reduced to tried. All parts of triade are different.

Without the cause it is only binary, and without pair unary unit. Without cause you may complete set by the rule you create, as David Gudeman said. Because the rule defines any behavior or proposition of subjective units - individuality. The rule replaces the cause by giving significance to units - the meaning, no cause, but reason, why it is reasonable? cuz the rule be.

These sets are always incomplete, because the rule is not a cause. You can choose should you follow the game rule or not, and the result will be is some the sector of probability, but causal things either est or not - you have no choice if it the cause.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question; replace the example Man(x) with the new example Red(x) and the question still stand, while your answer does not.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ofc you are right, because this is not equal replace. Language is not totally formal system. Natural math have only two numbers 1 and 2, all other are complied from them by the recurrence rule, and ect rules. But language is founded not on rules and only 1 pair. Language is founded on causal of process. Man have self ergo, X can replace but only form of it's significance. X have no ergo, and have no self, it is empty memory cell, just empty symbol with nothing inside.

Comment: What it X? can you answer? nope, because X is this you can to say, you cant say X=X - it is senseless. X is something that not exist. Man, natural word, is something that exist. You can't replace causal set to elementary without loss the completeness